# ASP.NET MVC - Uploading an image to Amazon S3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, amazon-s3, asp.net-4.0

I have my image from Request.Files[0]. Now, how do I upload this image to S3? I see that in the AWS .NET API you have to specify ContentBody when putting an object which is a string. How would I get the content body of my file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var file = Request.Files[0];
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.BucketName = "mybucket"
request.ContentType = contentType;
request.Key = key;
request.InputStream = file.InputStream;
s3Client.PutObject(request);
```

Answer (score 11):

Slightly more detail with how to use folders and to grant all users read-only access.
Html:

C#

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
   if (file.ContentLength > 0) // accept the file
        {
            string accessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
            string secretKey = "122334XXXXXXXXXX";
            AmazonS3 client;
            using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey))
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
      request.WithBucketName("mybucket")
     .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
     .WithKey("testfolder/test.jpg").InputStream = file.InputStream;
       S3Response response = client.PutObject(request);
            }
```

More detail is available here: http://bradoyler.com/post/3614362044/uploading-an-image-with-aws-sdk-for-net-c

Comment: Blog post is dead link.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a Base64-encoded string, but you should check the S3 documentation to be sure.  If it is, you should use [Convert.ToBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and pass it the byte array.

Here's some sample code you can try.  I haven't tested it, but it should help you get the right idea:

```
if (Request.Files.Count >= 1) {
    var file = Request.Files[0];
    var fileContents = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(fileContents, 0, file.ContentLength);
    var fileBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContents);

    // now you can send fileBase64String to the S3 uploader
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, but what did work was using file.InputStream as the InputStream property of a PutObjectRequest object. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
                PurObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                    Key =  string.Format("folderyouwanttoplacethefile/{0}", file.FileName),
                    InputStream = file.InputStream
                };

                YourS3client.PutObject(request);
```